# Python writing in files from a specific line

Tags: python, input, printing, output

is there a python function to write in a file from a specific line , I mean if I know the index of the line is there any possibility to begin writing from that line ?

Comment: yes there's a possibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can use this simple process**

```
source_file = open("file.txt", "r")
file_data = list(source_file.read())
source_file.close()
file_data.insert(position, data)
open("file.txt", "wb").write(file_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any way to do that in the way you are trying to

Alternatively, read the file into a string, then use **list methods** to insert your data.

```
source_file = open("myfile", "r")
file_data = list(source_file.read())
source_file.close()
file_data.insert(position, data)
open("myfile", "wb").write(file_data)
```